# Aviary Save image over existing image

Tags: php, jquery, aviary

I am integrating Aviary into my web app to modify images.

It is correctly loading the images and I am able to edit them. I then wish to overwrite the original image with the edited one on save.

I can't find an example of how to this. Documentation says to use the onSave method but provides no further information.

My current onSave method:

```
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
    img.src = newURL;
}
```

From old documentation it mentions postUrl but this has now been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look with this question, as Miki mentioned, you can pass the URL that Aviary generates to your server and upload the new photo from there.

[Save a picture in S3 from a temporary URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500057/save-a-picture-in-s3-from-a-temporary-url)